# Read log file as python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have sample log file in which for each msisdn value(**"msisdn":"22969000034"**) there are different state values like ('**"state":"COMPLETED"**', '**"state":"IN_PROGRESS"**' & **"state":"ENTERED"**). I have to create a report as "msisdn, requestID, state1(as ENTERED),state2(as IN_PROGRESS),state3(as COMPLETED), Notification. I am new in python and trying to read log file as dictionary but i am not able to get the relevant output. Please help me to understand. Pleas find the below sample log file and code.

Log file:-

{"methodName":"offlineNotifQueueListener()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.jms.listener.impl.ActiveMqListener","text":"Processing Offline request","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27","orgTransactionID":"895139242296900003","msisdn":"22969000034","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-03-24T22:59:59+0100","state":"ENTERED"}
{"methodName":"addNotificationText()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.service.notification.impl.MSProductNotificationImpl","text":"Evaluating notification for product : 1399","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27","orgTransactionID":"895139242296900003","msisdn":"22969000034","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-03-24T22:59:59+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"}
{"methodName":"executeConstraint()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.service.constraint.impl.MSConstraintsImpl","text":"Executing constraint : OfferCHeck","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27","orgTransactionID":"895139242296900003","msisdn":"22969000034","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"NA","transactionDateTime":"2020-03-24T22:59:59+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"}
{"methodName":"getValueFromAIR()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.service.templateparam.impl.TemplateParamServiceImpl","text":"Evaluating parameter --\u003e ${OFFER_123089_VALUE}","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27","orgTransactionID":"895139242296900003","msisdn":"22969000034","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-03-24T22:59:59+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"}
{"methodName":"executeCommand","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.service.templateparam.impl.TemplateParamServiceImpl","text":"Executing  AIR command ---\u003e GetOffers","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27","orgTransactionID":"895139242296900003","msisdn":"22969000034","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-03-24T22:59:59+0100","state":"COMPLETED"}

Code:

```
with open(BASE_LOCATION+'/msLog.log', 'r') as readfile1:
#    readfile1 = readfile1.replace('"', '')
    output = csv.DictReader(readfile1)
    for row in output:
#        row1 = re.sub("{", "", row2)
#        row = re.sub(""", "", row1)
        #print(value)
        for key, value in row.items():
#            print(value)
            for data in value.keys():
                print(data)
                if data.get(state) == ENTERED:
                    msd = value.get('msisdn')
                    state1 = value.get('state')
                    rid = value.get('requestID')
                    txt = msd, rid, state1
                    list1.append(txt)
                    print(msd,state1)
                elif key.get('state') == '"IN_PROGRESS"' and key.get('msisdn') == msd:
                    state2 = key.get('state')
                    list1.append(state2)
                elif key.get('state') == '"COMPLETED"' and key.get('msisdn') == msd:
                    state3 = key.get('state')
                    text = key.get('text')
                    list1.append(state3)
                    list1.append(text)
list.append(list1)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Later Edit:**

If you log has multiple lines:

```
line 1 {"methodName":"offlineNotifQueueListener()",
.....
"state":"COMPLETED"}
line n {"methodName":"offlineNotifQueueListener()",
.....
"state":"COMPLETED"}
```

Replace (1) and (2) with this block:

```
with open('test.log', 'r') as f:
  data = f.readlines()

data = json.loads("[" \
  + ','.join(x.strip("\n").replace("} {", "}, {") for x in data) \
  + "]")
```

Explanations:

-`readlines` : stores all lines as elements inside a list e.g. `[line1,line2 ....]`; The downside is that each element ends with `\n` the list becomes `[line1\n,line2\n ...]`

- `strip` removes the "\n" at the end of each "line"
- `replace` - adds comma to dictionaries that are inside a line:

  `... "state":"ENTERED"} {"methodName":"addNotificationText()" ...`

becomes

`... "state":"ENTERED"}, {"methodName":"addNotificationText()" ...`

Then we `join` each line of list by a comma `,` data becoming a long string `{},{},{},{},{},{},{}` from all lines, from all ids.

- `[`+above+`]`

So that looks like a collection (list?) of dictionaries (data is a string) so you can parse it to generate a report. As we know, a list starts with `[` and ends with `]`, so the string becomes `[{},{},{}]`.

- `json.loads` parses the string ( `"[{},{},{}]"` ) into actual valid Python data `[{},{},{}]`, list of dictionaries which can be used as you please.

Full edited code:

```
import json

with open('test.log', 'r') as f:
  data = f.readlines()

data = json.loads("[" \
  + ','.join(x.strip("\n").replace("} {", "}, {") for x in data) \
  + "]")
```

While the output remains the same from the initial answer.

**End Edit**

Here's an approach:

I would transform the file output in a list of dictionaries(1), then I would transform (change type)(2) the string into list of dictionaries, then I would retrieve the info as needed, using keys values as you intended (3).

```
import json

with open('test.log', 'r') as f:
  data = '['+f.readlines()[0].replace('} {','}, {')+']'                   #(1)

data = json.loads(data)                                                   #(2)

for x in data:                                                            #(3)
  print(f"msisdn: {x['msisdn']}, status: {x['state']}, requestID: {x['requestID']}")
```

Output:

```
msisdn: 22969000034, status: ENTERED, requestID: OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
msisdn: 22969000034, status: IN_PROGRESS, requestID: OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
msisdn: 22969000034, status: IN_PROGRESS, requestID: OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
msisdn: 22969000034, status: IN_PROGRESS, requestID: OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
msisdn: 22969000034, status: COMPLETED, requestID: OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
```

Or if as you tried, want to store the msisdn and requestid into separate lists, based on their status (entered,progr, completed), you could use this (bellow replaces step 3 of the above code):

```
_list_entered=[]
_list_completed=[]
_list_inprogress=[]

for x in data:
  if x['state'] == "ENTERED":
    _list_entered.append([x['msisdn'],x['requestID']])
  elif x['state'] == "IN_PROGRESS":
    _list_inprogress.append([x['msisdn'],x['requestID']])
  elif x['state'] == "COMPLETED":
    _list_completed.append([x['msisdn'],x['requestID']])

print("IDs with Entered")
for x in _list_entered:
  print(*x)

print("IDs with IN_PROGRESS")
for x in _list_inprogress:
  print(*x)

print("IDs with Completed")
for x in _list_completed:
  print(*x)
```

Output:

```
IDs with Entered
22969000034 OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
IDs with IN_PROGRESS
22969000034 OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
22969000034 OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
22969000034 OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
IDs with Completed
22969000034 OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27
```

Comment: Your approach is working but it is only for first occurrence of line. Whenever i am trying to print the values output is coming only from 1st line of log file. I am confuse in "data = '['+f.readlines()[0].replace('} {','}, {')+']'"  where f.readlines()[0] is giving outpit only for 1st line of log file.

Comment: Please suggest how to read all line from log file by using data = '['+f.readlines()[0].replace('} {','}, {')+']'.

Comment: That's correct; edited the answer with an approach that covers multiple lines and added explanations for the `[`+..+`]` trick, between "later edit" and "end edit". Don't hesitate in letting me know if something comes up/needs more clarifications.